# Android BLE discovery internal error

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
02-09 13:48:32.063  22171-22538/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ Batch record : [0, 0, 0, 0, -8, 108, 92, -85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 6, 18, 9, 65, 108, 108, 105, 101, 45, 49, 49, 49, 53, 53, 51, 48, 51, 54, 52, 48, 2, 10, 0, 5, 3, -30, -1, 10, 24, 0, 100, 23, 107, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -85, 4, 0, 31, 2, 1, 6, 18, 9, 65, 108, 108, 105, 101, 45, 50, 48, 49, 53, 52, 51, 48, 48, 48, 52, 57, 2, 10, 0, 5, 3, -30, -1, 10, 24, 0, 109, 3, 96, -32, 27, -52, 0, 0, -78, 2, 0, 31, 2, 1, 6, 18, 9, 65, 108, 108, 105, 101, 45, 49, 49, 49, 53, 53, 49, 48, 49, 56, 51, 51, 2, 10, 0, 5, 3, -30, -1, 10, 24, 0, -46, -56, -92, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -69, 5, 0, 31, 2, 1, 6, 18, 9, 65, 108, 108, 105, 101, 45, 50, 48, 49, 53, 52, 51, 48, 48, 48, 52, 49, 2, 10, 0, 5, 3, -30, -1, 10, 24, 0, 49, 1, 96, -32, 27, -52, 0, 0, -67, 5, 0, 31, 2, 1, 6, 18, 9, 65, 108, 108, 105, 101, 45, 50, 48, 49, 53, 52, 51, 48, 48, 48, 49, 53, 2, 10, 0, 5, 3, -30, -1, 10, 24, 0, -19, 1, 96, -32, 27, -52, 0, 0, -73, 88, 0, 31, 2, 1, 6, 18, 9, 65, 108, 108, 105, 101, 45, 49, 54, 49, 53, 52, 57, 48, 48, 48, 53, 52, 2, 10, 0, 5, 3, -30, -1, 10, 24, 0]
02-09 13:48:32.071  22171-22538/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ ScanRecord : [1, 6]
02-09 13:48:32.073  22171-22538/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ ScanRecord : [53, 51, 48, 51, 54, 52, 48, 2, 10, 0, 5, 3, -30, -1, 10, 24, 0, 100, 23, 107, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -85, 4, 0, 31, 2, 1, 6, 18, 9, 65, 108, 108, 105, 101, 45, 50, 48, 49, 53, 52, 51, 48, 48, 48, 52, 57, 2, 10]
02-09 13:48:32.073  22171-22538/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ ScanRecord : [-52, 0, 0, -78, 2, 0, 31, 2, 1, 6, 18, 9, 65, 108, 108, 105, 101, 45, 49, 49, 49, 53, 53, 49, 48, 49, 56, 51, 2, 10, 0, 5, 3, -30, -1, 10, 24, 0, -46, -56, -92, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, -69, 5, 0, 31, 2, 1, 6, 18, 9, 65, 108, 108, 105, 101, 45, 50, 48, 49, 53, 52, 51, 48, 48, 48, 52, 49, 2, 10, 0, 5, 3, -30]
02-09 13:48:32.136  22171-22538/? E/BluetoothServiceJni﹕ An exception was thrown by callback 'btgattc_batchscan_reports_cb'.
02-09 13:48:32.147  22171-22538/? E/BluetoothServiceJni﹕ java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -67
            at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.extractBytes(GattService.java:1153)
            at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.parseFullResults(GattService.java:1128)
            at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.parseBatchScanResults(GattService.java:1075)
            at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.onBatchScanReports(GattService.java:1034)
```

Is there anything i can do with it?

Comment: This is a JNI error, most probably you should change your scan parameters to see if it works. this is because some manufacturer using vanilla android, which has issues in BLE(as a lot of hardware dependent there)

Comment: can you send me vanilla android internal BLE bugs links please?

Comment: There is no bug registered, as there are features which are hardware dependent, and only manufacturers enables those features, and can have bugs there.